# What is cause of 404 Page Delay

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

When a website is developed and works fine and then deployed, when some users open the site it initially shows a 404 page not found error, then after a short time the home page is shown.  The site is built with asp.net, running in IIS with an SSL certificate.  What is the cause of this and how can it be prevented?

Googled "404 page not found delay" - this provided several answers but mostly just generally about a page not found and not about a delay

Comment: Have you ever had your browsers developer tools open and observed the network traffic when this happens to see if any requests are 404'ing out?

Comment: @TimothyG. Thanks.  I will check.  It is just confusing that they show 404 temporarily then open the relevant page

Comment: What are "some users"? What are the URLs that 404 errors are related to? The more you know of them, the better you might understand the situation and find the culprit. In real world site deployment, any kind of errors can be expected from DNS/CDN issues to server side problems, as so many things are involved.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks.  Some users - I mean it is running on a windows 2016 server and it is fairly consistently showing a 404 initially for all users, the the page is rendered

Comment: You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.